# defined standards from RFC5321 and RFC5322

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using Mail() in PHP and as of 4/1/2020 all my site has stopped working because of:
"
Customers emails can be rejected by our SMTP server because it does not comply with the defined standards from RFC5321 and RFC5322.
*1. The header of your e-mail must contain a valid "Date:" entry according to RFC2822: 
  2. The following field types must be unique: "Date:", "From:", "Sender:", "To:", "CC:", "BCC:", "Subject:"
  3. If the above field types are included, they must not be empty and have to be syntactically correct
Note: The field types "To:", "CC:" and "BCC:" can, of course, contain several recipients."*

do you have any Example how this is done ?

my original code which used to work is :

```
  $to = "awk_grep@yahoo.com";
  $subject = "Who are You?.";
  $CC = "No CC";
  $BC = "No BC";
  $from="DO_NOT_REPLY";
  $headers .= "From: $whoareyou\n";
  $headers .= "Date: $hdrdate\n";
  $headers .= "X-Sender: $from\n";
  $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-10859-1\r\n";
```

Comment: And did you look at [RFC5321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) and compare it to your outgoing mail payload? If so, which concrete attempts did you take to rectify?

Comment: i am looking for a working example at this late hour,, I need to see one that is working so I can fix mine,,